# record rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run tf tf_echo /map /base_link and compute exact data needed:

```
...
At time 1407419581.729
- Translation: [-8.999, -22.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.000, 0.850. 0.526]
                 in RPY [0.000. -0.000, 2.034]
...
```

Is there a way to record this streaming data with rosbag record?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189336/record-rosrun-tf-tf_echo-/map-/base_link/) by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if this is the best approach, but it should work. I would write a node that publishes the transformations between /map and /base_link. In order to get the transformation you should use "lookupTransform" as you can see here:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29

As you can see, the transformation can be published to a topic of your choice. Whatever it is, you can then use this command in order to record it:

```
rosbag record -O subset /chosentopic
```

---

Originally posted by [lucaluca](https://answers.ros.org/users/19657/lucaluca/) with karma: 74 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thanks, I thought this may be the case. Though, I hoped I may already record this data since it is already streaming in when I run:

tf tf_echo /map /base_link

**Comment by [lucaluca](https://answers.ros.org/users/19657/lucaluca/) on 2014-08-07**:
@Orso since the help file of rosbag record says "Record a bag file with the contents of specified topics" and it seems there's not a topic with your data, I'm assuming this cannot be done directly. You can wait to see if some other user knows a direct approach :)

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2014-08-07**:
A tf listener is required to record a transformation of a coordinate frame from tf to a bag file. No way around it that I could find. Thanks for the direction lucaluca.